# Array of objects being corrupted after using cout

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers

After a few days of my question being closed, and my edits that would answer all of the questions in the comments not being approved, I have decided to re-post with a few changes.

I am new to c++, but I am an experienced programmer. I am trying to create a chess engine, as I have done it in python but I want it faster. I am storing my chess board as a 2d array of Piece pointers.

**chessBoard.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pieces.h"

class Chess
{
private:
    Piece* board[8][8] = {};
public:
    Chess();
    void print_board();
};
```

**pieces.h**

```
enum PieceType {
    pawn, knight, bishop, rook, queen, king
};

enum Colour {
    white, black
};

class Piece {
protected:
    PieceType pieceType;
    Colour colour;
public:
    char symbol;
    Piece(Colour colour);
};

class Pawn : public Piece {
public:
    Pawn(Colour colour);
};

// The rest of the pieces are defined in the same way
```

**pieces.cpp**

```
#include "pieces.h"

Piece::Piece(Colour colour) {
    this->colour = colour;
}

Pawn::Pawn(Colour colour) : Piece(colour) {
    this->pieceType = pawn;
    this->symbol = (colour == white) ? 'P' : 'p';
}

// The rest of the pieces constructors are the same
```

**chessBoard.cpp**

```
Chess::Chess()
{
    // The back row of black pieces
    Rook bq_r(black);
    Knight bq_n(black);
    Bishop bq_b(black);
    Queen bq_q(black);
    King bk_k(black);
    Bishop bk_b(black);
    Knight bk_n(black);
    Rook bk_r(black);

    board[0][0] = &bq_r;
    board[0][1] = &bq_n;
    board[0][2] = &bq_b;
    board[0][3] = &bq_q;
    board[0][4] = &bk_k;
    board[0][5] = &bk_b;
    board[0][6] = &bk_n;
    board[0][7] = &bk_r;
}

void Chess::print_board() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (board[i][j]) {
                std::cout << board[i][j]->symbol;
                std::cout << " ";
            } else {
                std::cout << ". ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "chessBoard.h"

int main()
{
    Chess chess;
    chess.print_board();
    return 1;
}
```

I understand this is a lot of code, and I wish I could post only the relevant information, but unfortunately I have no clue what the problem was, and most of the comments on my last post asked for more info. If needed the complete code, it can be found here: https://github.com/kiran-isaac/chess-engine/tree/test.

**The Expected Outcome**

```
r n b q k b m r 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . .
```

**The Actual Outcome**

```
r   �   � � � r 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . .
```

The first rook is always correct. Everything after that changes with each running of the program.

The cause seems to be that the everything in the board array is corrupted. It is all fine until it hits the "printBoard" function. As soon as it encounters the first cout, everything in the array becomes corrupted. I can work around this by having it store the output in a string and outputting it afterwords, but this still causes the array to be corrupted, albeit after I have sucessfully printed it.

I hope that someone can help, as I am enjoying development with c++, and I don't want to give up on this project.

This is a screenshot of the value of the board array from line 1 of the printBoard() function. This is how it should be.

[image: Screenshot from when it works]

This is a screenshot from after the first iteration, after encountering the std::cout on line 4 of the printBoard() function.

[image: Screenshot from after it doesnt]

I have been stuck on this problem for 2 days, researching and debugging, and I've found nothing. I'm sure it's something simple I'm doing wrong, I just can't find it. Please comment if you need any more info.

Thank you

Comment: At a first glance you seem to be taking the address of temporary objects. This is UB. I assume that when you call `std::cout::operator<<` it overwrites the stack frame of the constructor and hence your specific objects. Use smart pointers, and dynamic allocation (or members variables)

Comment: Coming from Python, you will probably want to spend some time reading about _object lifetimes_.  Particularly _automatic storage_.  C++ demands that you think about _how_ and _when_ objects reach their end-of-life.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to post this as an answer, with an example of how I would do this?

Comment: You are missing header guards and also the complete header defining `Chess`.

Comment: I forgot to make it public, apologies

Comment: I know, ive tried to minimise the amount of code on the page so i've included the most relevant bits. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects `bq_r` etc. defined in your `Chess::Chess()` constructor have their lifetimes end when the constructor finishes, so the array is full of dangling pointers which can't validly be used.

I'd recommend instead:

```
#include <memory>

class Chess
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Piece> board[8][8] = {};
public:
    Chess();
    void print_board();
};

Chess::Chess()
{
    board[0][0] = std::make_unique<Rook>(black);
    board[0][1] = std::make_unique<Knight>(black);
    board[0][2] = std::make_unique<Bishop>(black);
    board[0][3] = std::make_unique<Queen>(black);
    board[0][4] = std::make_unique<King>(black);
    board[0][5] = std::make_unique<Bishop>(black);
    board[0][6] = std::make_unique<Knight>(black);
    board[0][7] = std::make_unique<Rook>(black);

    for (auto& pawn_pos : board[1])
         pawn_pos = std::make_unique<Pawn>(black);

    // ...
}
```

Since the `unique_ptr`s will clean up by deleting a pointer to base class `Piece` which actually points at other class types, that class needs a virtual destructor:

```
class Piece {
public:
    // ...
    virtual ~Piece() = default;
};
```

Comment: `Piece` doesn't have a `virtual` destructor, so you might want to add that to the answer too.

Comment: Thank you, i didnt realise just how much more difficult c++ is than python!

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer fixes the object lifetime problem by using dynamic allocation to create heap objects, but it should be noted that polymorphism on a base class pointer doesn't require dynamic allocation (I'm assuming you intend to add `virtual` functions later).

The various derived pieces could simply be data members of the `Chess` object, which often offers better performance and fewer pitfalls than dynamic allocation (moving the pointers around the board correctly may also be needlessly cumbersome with `unique_ptr`):

```
class Chess {
private:
    Piece* board[8][8] = {};

    Rook m_white_rook;
    Knight m_white_knight;
    // ...all pieces here...

public:
    Chess() : 
        m_white_rook(Colour::white), 
        m_white_knight(Colour::white),
        // ...initialize pieces here...
    {
        board[0][0] = &m_white_rook;
        board[0][1] = &m_white_knight;
        // ...assign simple, non-owning pointers to the board...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this is probably a better solution in this case. I am going to use the first one however, as i need to learn how to to these kind of things